restrict from adding a similar record
I have three objects - Apartment, Subject, Vote. When creating a new vote, I must enter the vote name, the apartment that voted, the subject of the vote and the vote itself (For it of Against it). I want to restrict the user from creating two records on the same object from the same apartment.
For example, if apartment A voted "For it" on a subject of "Paint the walls", I don't want there to be another record of apartment A on the same subject with the vote "Against it". I can however edit the existing record and change the vote.
Also, while editing the record, it must check that it doesn't match any other existing records as well. any suggestions?

All you need to do is add a Unique Index field on the Vote object, and automate it to make a unique value of Apartment-Subject using a Flow. Salesforce will automatically reject duplicates based on this unique value.

Do you mind elaborating how to add the Unique Index field? should it be a checked checkbox?

@DanielBena Create a text field, 36 characters long, and choose Unique / "Treat "ABC" and "abc" as different values (case sensitive)". The automation is a Before Save Record-Triggered Flow that assigns the values in the two lookup fields (Apartment, Subject) to this unique indexed field using the formula {!$Record.Apartment__c}&{!$Record.Subject__c} (modify for your field names).

Thank you for your help, it worked

An alternative solution to this would be to utilise Flow to add an error when attempting to save the record.
In this approach, you'd use a Record Triggered Flow on the Vote object that retrieves any records where the Apartment and Subject values are the same. Then, check if the count of those retrieved records is greater than zero, and if add a Custom Error element to inform the user that they have already recorded a Vote for that Apartment/Subject combination.

Thank you for the alternative approach, I'll be sure to try it too
